# Security implications of allowing DROP privileges on shared hosting

Tags: mysql, shared-hosting

I am curious to know the pros and cons of denying DROP permissions to shared hosting accounts.

Obviously there is the chance of someone removing their entire database and not having permissions to recreate it, but I'm more concerned with whether this can allow them to affect other databases in any way?

Would it actually lower security on shared hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Generally we allow each user to have the ability to their own databases - full read/write abilities -

BUT we do not allow them access to others

are you using a control panel ?  or just vanilla hosting...

Most control panels will help you do this automagically

Either way - if you limit the user to specific rights and specific databases - you should be fine.

Comment: cheers, Its just plain old hosting, no control panel. I just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 0):

I would not give your users `DROP DATABASE` without some kind of control panel. Presumably you want to limit the number of databases each user owns, so you wouldn't give them `CREATE DATABASE`, so it could get old fast for your support team if they keep having to recreate user databases, reset their permissions, etc..